# Javascript - replace pattern but keep alphabets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I was wondering, what is the best way to implement the following case:

```
vm.elasticQuery = userQuery.replace(/~='[a-zA-Z]+'/g,':*[a-zA-Z]+*')
```

In other words, I would like to replace every pattern that looks like this `~='SomeLetters'` to a pattern that looks like this `:*SomeLetters*`. Take into account that I do not want to remove/change the alphabets but only the outside.

Your help is appriciated.

Comment: The rule is the same across all NFA regex libraries: use a capturing group in the pattern and replacement backreferences in the replacement -> `.replace(/~='([a-zA-Z]+)'/g,':*$1*')`